# error al publicar api windows server 2008 IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

Cree un pequeño servicio API en framework 4.8, cuando lo ejecuto en el IIS express funciona correctamente, pero al publicarlo en un servidor windows 2008 con IIS 7.5 sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que he leido y entiendo del mensaje es un problema de enrutamiento. Pero instale en mi maquina local el IIS para windows 10 e hice el despliegue igual que en el server 2008 y funciona bien.

En el web config tengo lo siguiente:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: por el error que te muestra, yo creo que mas bien debe ser un error dentro de tu publicación en IIS, que configuración le asignaste a los enlaces de tu sitio.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea configuraciones por defect, lo deje en el puerto 80 vamnalizacion integrada 4.0

Comment: Tu consulta va sobre el puerto 9000, entonces tendrias que modificar tu api para acceder directo a localhost, o a tu ip, dominio sin el puerto